# Ubuntu Studio installation stops at busybox initramfs prompt

Tags: filesystem

Ubuntu Studio is not installing.

```
(Initramfs) mount: mounting /dev /loop0 on/filesystem.squashfs failed: invalid argument
Can not mount /dev /loop0 (/CD-ROM/Casper filesystem squashes) on /filesystem.quashfs
```

[image: photo of screen showing initramfs BusyBox prompt]

Comment: If you have another desktop Linux use it's own tool instead of Unetbootin. If you have Windows then use Balena Etcher. The error message suggests some possibilities: 1. faulty USB stick, 2. corrupt ISO, 3. something else went wrong

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)